# Which should I use: 'near of the place' or 'near the place'?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

Which should I use: **'near of'** or **'near'**?
Can I use both?
For example:

> *"I live **near of** the river."*
> *"I live **near** the river."*

Are they grammatically correct?
Is there any difference between them?

Comment: The second one. As far as I know, [near](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/near) is a preposition here, so you don't need another preposition (*of*).

Comment: The first one is _not_ grammatically correct. Forget it.